# List of data frames with the same number of variables and delete duplicates inside one variable and do the same in the rest of the data frames

Tags: r, list, function, lapply, nested-datalist

I have the following list of data frames and each data frame has 3 variables (a, b and c)

```
my.list <- list(d1, d2, d3, d4)
```

Inside my data frame, I have duplicated strings in "a" and I want to delete the rows with duplicated values

The current code i am using:

```
my.listnew <- lapply(my.list, function(x) unique(x["a"]))
```

The problem i have with this code is that the other 2 columns  "b" and "c" are gone and I want to keep them, while the duplicated rows are deleted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `duplicated` to remove the duplicated values in column `a` while keeping other columns.

```
my.listnew <- lapply(my.list, function(x) x[!duplicated(x$a), ])
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference, tidyverse style of doing it-

```r
set.seed(1)
my.list <- list(d1 = data.frame(a = sample(letters[1:3], 5, T),
                                b = rnorm(5),
                                c = rnorm(5)), 
                d2 = data.frame(a = sample(letters[1:3], 5, T),
                                b = rnorm(5),
                                c = rnorm(5)), 
                d3 = data.frame(a = sample(letters[1:3], 5, T),
                                b = rnorm(5),
                                c = rnorm(5)))
library(tidyverse)
map(my.list, ~ .x %>% filter(!duplicated(a)) )
#> $d1
#>   a         b          c
#> 1 a 1.5952808  0.5757814
#> 2 c 0.3295078 -0.3053884
#> 3 b 0.4874291  0.3898432
#> 
#> $d2
#>   a          b         c
#> 1 b  0.2522234 0.3773956
#> 2 a -0.8919211 0.1333364
#> 
#> $d3
#>   a          b          c
#> 1 a -0.2357066  1.1519118
#> 2 c -0.4333103 -0.4295131
#> 3 b -0.6494716  1.2383041
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

If you also want to combine the dataframes in output you may use `map_dfr` instead of `map` in above

Comment: Or maybe just `map(my.list, ~distinct(.x, a))`?

Comment: No @dash2, it only gives column `a` in output

Comment: Ah ok. `map(my.list, ~distinct(.x, a, .keep_all = TRUE))` then.

Comment: @dash2 Thanks for value addition.  I wan't aware of this `.keep_all` argument.  :)

Answer (score 0):

We can use `subset` without any anonymous function

```
out <- lapply(my.list, subset, subset = !duplicated(a))
```

---

Or using `data.table` with `unique`

```
library(data.table)
out <- lapply(my.list, function(dat) unique(as.data.table(dat), by = 'a'))
```